# calculating summary statistics for multiple ranges in data frame

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a large data frame "table" as:

```
  Year Month        Model Scenario Longitude Latitude tas_month pr_month
1 2000     1 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     24.20    40.63
2 2000     2 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.05    54.20
3 2000     3 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.19    36.87
4 2000     4 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.44   126.47
5 2000     5 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.36   282.44
6 2000     6 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.71   284.68
```

And I want to create a new data frame that has the `mean(tas_month)` and `mean(pr_month)` for each period of five years, using a `group_by(Month, Longitude, Latitude, Model, Scenario)`. This new data frame must also have a new column where each row has the value of the 5 years period where those values belong.

```
  Period Month        Model Scenario Longitude Latitude tas_month pr_month
1 1     1 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     24.20    40.63
2 2     2 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.05    54.20
3 3     3 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.19    36.87
4 4     4 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.44   126.47
5 5     5 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.36   282.44
6 6     6 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45      9.57   -84.53     25.71   284.68
```

I already created a vector with these periods of five years as:

```
fiveyears <- seq(2000, 2100, 5)
```

But still haven´t been able to figure it out how to compute the means. I was thinking of something like this "pseudo" code but it still is very rough:

```
for (i in seq_along(fiveyears)){
  table %>% filter(Year < (i+5) & Year >= i) %>% 
  group_by(Month, Longitude, Latitude, Model, Scenario) %>% 
  summarise(pr_month = mean(pr_month), tas_month = mean(tas_month))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data concerns only Year 2000, so here's something that we can use:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2000:2011, each = 3), x = rnorm(36))
```

Your idea is good but we can make it even more succinct:

```
df %>% group_by(Year %/% 5) %>% summarize(y = mean(x))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   `Year%/%5`      y
#        <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1        400  0.334
# 2        401  0.116
# 3        402 -0.222
```

where `%/%` indicates integer division. If needed, you may then change the first column name and normalize its value accordingly.

Update:

```
df %>% group_by(Year %/% 5, Month, Longitude, Latitude, Model, Scenario) %>% 
  summarize(tas_month = mean(tas_month), pr_month = mean(pr_month)) %>% 
  rename("Period" = `Year%/%5`) %>% 
  transform(Period = Period - min(df$Year %/% 5) + 1)
#   Period Month Longitude Latitude        Model Scenario tas_month pr_month
# 1      1     1      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     24.20    40.63
# 2      1     2      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     25.05    54.20
# 3      1     3      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     25.19    36.87
# 4      1     4      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     25.44   126.47
# 5      1     5      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     25.36   282.44
# 6      1     6      9.57   -84.53 ccsm4_r1i1p1    rpc45     25.71   284.68
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked pretty well.. I ended up spending some time figuring it out how to change the first column values. I wrote my answer after yours. I imagine it could have been written in fewer lines... I hope some day....

Comment: @Guillermo.D, see the update, I tried to obtain your desired result, hopefully it also works with your full dataset. Perhaps `Period` is not what you wanted? I assumed that it only described the 5 years period and doesn't concern any other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice by @Julius I ended up with this. Not as clean or elegant as I would like, but at least I hope it can give some ideas to someone having a similar issue:

```
tbl_month_5years <- table %>% 
  group_by(Year %/% 5, Month, Longitude, Latitude, Model, Scenario) %>%
  summarise(tas_mean = mean(tas_month), pr_mean = mean(pr_month)) %>%
  rename(period = `Year%/%5`)

periods_5years <- tbl_month_5years %>% group_by(period) %>%    
  summarise(n())

years5 <- as.data.frame(seq(2000, 2095, 5))
years5 <-years5 %>% rename(ini_year = `seq(2000, 2095, 5)`)
years5 <- cbind(years5, periods_5years)

tbl_month_5years <- tbl_month_5years %>% 
  left_join(years5, by = "period") %>% select(-`n()`)
```